# another "must specify a attribute type for metadata element" question

Tags: metadata-api

I solved my metadata connection problem so now have hit the next obstacle, trying to create a  com.sforce.soap.metadata.Folder object using

```
com.sforce.soap.metadata.Folder  aFolderObj = new com.sforce.soap.metadata.Folder();
aFolderObj.setFullName("MikeOwesMeABeer");
aFolderObj.setFolderShares( folderShare_arry);

Metadata[] meta_arry = new Metadata[1];
meta_arry[0] = (Metadata) aFolderObj;   

AsyncResult[] ar_arry = theApp.sfConnectionSandboxMetadata.create( meta_arry);
```

this last line throws error:

```
Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element
```

There are references to how create() has problems with custom objects but Folder is not custom. How must I adjust my create() to get this working?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, how did you create the above classes around the Metadata API, it looks like your in Java yes? The error message relates to the xsi:type attribute missing, which tells Salesforce the type of Metadata component. This is normally added by the Web Service stack your using, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
1-> needed to connect with an authEndPoint of 28 instead of 24
2-> metadataConnection.create() wants to see a more-explicit class of Folder, like ReportFolder.

To wit:

```
com.sforce.soap.metadata.Folder aFolderObj = new com.sforce.soap.metadata.Folder();
aFolderObj.setName("RameshOwesMeBeer");
aFolderObj.setFullName("RameshOwesMeSeveralBeers");
aFolderObj.setAccessType(FolderAccessTypes.Shared);
aFolderObj.setFolderShares( folderShare_arry);

Metadata[] metadataObj_arry = new Metadata[1];
metadataObj_arry[0] = (Metadata) aFolderObj;    

AsyncResult[] ar_arry = theApp.sfConnectionSandboxMetadata.create( metadataObj_arry);
```

does not work
whereas

```
com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReportFolder aRepFolderObj = new com.sforce.soap.metadata.ReportFolder();
aRepFolderObj.setName("RameshOwesMeBeer");
aRepFolderObj.setFullName("RameshOwesMeSeveralBeers");
aRepFolderObj.setAccessType(FolderAccessTypes.Shared);
aRepFolderObj.setFolderShares( folderShare_arry);

Metadata[] metadataObj_arry = new Metadata[1];
metadataObj_arry[0] = (Metadata) aRepFolderObj; 

AsyncResult[] ar_arry = theApp.sfConnectionSandboxMetadata.create( metadataObj_arry);
```

does

Thanks to all to read

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve